# How to set end position of parallax ellements

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm quite new to JavaScript and try to set end position to my parallax element.

**Here is my code:**

```
var f1 = document.getElementById("f1");
var f2 = document.getElementById('f2');
var f3 = document.getElementById('f3');
var f4 = document.getElementById('f4');

function initParallax() {
  f1.style.left = ((window.pageYOffset / 10) - 300) + "px";
  f2.style.left = (window.pageYOffset / 5) + "px";
  f3.style.left = ((window.pageYOffset / 8) + 40) + "px";

  f4.style.right = ((window.pageYOffset / 6) - 200) + "px";
  f4.style.bottom = ((window.pageYOffset / 15)) + "px";
}

window.addEventListener("scroll", initParallax);
```

So, my parallax elements move through the whole display, but I want them stop at the middle of it.

Comment: did u end up getting it to work? I am trying to do a similar job.